# installation of xamarin with visual studio 2015

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, cross-platform

Now i am going on with the Installing Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015 Preview by following the below link:

http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/blagunas/archive/2014/11/14/installing-xamarin-for-visual-studio-2015-preview-side-by-side-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx

After downloading the xamarin for windows and restarted my visual studio 2015 but i can't able to see the **Mobile Apps** template.

I do not know where it's goes wrong and also tried with by Go to Add/Remove programs and search for Xamarin
and change for visula studio 2015.

If any one have idea about this can please help to sove this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have Visual Studio 2013 already installed?
Is so go to Control Panel, select Xamarin and press Change. In Xamarin Setup make sure that `Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015` is selected.
[image]

Comment: yes i did this after that i can't able to see the mobile apps template of xamarin

Comment: by following the above link

Comment: so `Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015` is installed in the Xamarin Setup? Have you restarted the machine after that?

Comment: is there any other way to get the tempelate

Comment: my advice is to remove all Xamarin products and reinstall them again from fresh. I had similar issue and this helped my back then..

Comment: what i did is create a new project select Android and download the xamarin from the offical and changed the following in control panel but i can't able to see the mobile apps templates

Comment: can you provide me the link which you followed to build multiple platform

Comment: http://www.cazzulino.com/install-xamarin-2015-preview.html  Is your Xamarin up to date or you're using an old version lacking VS2015 support? Why not go for VS2013??

Comment: actually i am new to xamarin development can you please guide me

Comment: if i go to the vs2013 which one should i use and how to merge the xamarin with the vs bro

Comment: is there any particular vs2013 should be downloaded for multiple platfrom

Comment: Any version of VS2013 should be fine there's a lot of materials online showing you how to install it

Comment: can you please tell me how to merge vs with xamarin

Comment: If you are on an alpha or beta channel, this might be the only way to do it without reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

Don't install the recommended edition. And be aware what options you select in the auto installer. Sometimes if you uninstall it and again install, the app templates appear back, though weird. Try it.

Comment: can you refer any proper link to follow the installation because i am new to this

Comment: can you refer any link

Comment: You can take a look at this if you are installing in Windows for doing Android development http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/

Comment: yes i am going on with windows cross platform to build for multiple platform

Comment: i need this for multiple platform

Comment: You can go through that it also includes iOS.. Just change it from the left menu...

Comment: need for multiple platform common lib as portable create project with mobile apps